# Dirac delta questions

Tags: dirac-delta

I'd like to ask for help in solving 3 I suppose quite easy questions about Dirac delta.

1. $$\delta (-x) = \delta (x)$$
2. $$\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|}\delta (x)$$
3. $$\delta ' (-x) = -\delta ' (x)$$

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What is your definition of $\delta$?

Comment: https://ibb.co/L6h2MvX - this is the definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the physicist definition of the Dirac delta distribution, where:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\delta(x)dx = f(0)$$
If this is the case, then the properties follow from:

1) $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(-x)dx = -\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(-y)\delta(y)dy =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\delta(y)dy$

2) $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(ax)dx = \frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\bigg{(}\frac{y}{a}\bigg{)}\delta(y)dy = \frac{1}{a}f(0) = \frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x)$

3) $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta'(-x)dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\delta(-x)dx =-\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}(f')(-x))\delta(x)dx =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f')(-x)\delta(x)dx =f'(0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\delta(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)(-\delta'(x))$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: the 3rd question - I have some issues understanding it. Can you write it a bit more explicitly, and I think there’s something wrong with the limits of integration. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wrote it more carefully now. Hope it helps you!

Comment: thank you ever so much! I felt that there was a minor issue about the limits of integration. Now I fully understand it!